# Text file processing

Tags: python, logging, text

i want to process a text file(log file) that is a collection of json based strings i want to extract a url but i am not able to get the string . can somebody guide me regarding that sorry if this is a trivial question as i am just a 1st year undergrad. I am using python.

```
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:32+05:30\",\"message\":\"Cannot determine default configuration path. No file [config.yml config.yaml] in [~/.cloudflared ~/.cloudflare-warp ~/cloudflare-warp /etc/cloudflared /usr/local/etc/cloudflared]\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:32+05:30\",\"message\":\"Version 2021.1.2\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:32+05:30\",\"message\":\"GOOS: linux, GOVersion: go1.15.6, GoArch: amd64\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:32+05:30\",\"message\":\"Environment variables map[logfile:./log.log proxy-dns-upstream:https://1.1.1.1/dns-query, https://1.0.0.1/dns-query url:http://localhost:8080]\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:32+05:30\",\"message\":\"cloudflared will not automatically update when run from the shell. To enable auto-updates, run cloudflared as a service: https://developers.cloudflare.com/argo-tunnel/reference/service/\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:32+05:30\",\"message\":\"Initial protocol h2mux\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:32+05:30\",\"message\":\"Starting metrics server on 127.0.0.1:34223/metrics\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"connIndex\":0,\"location\":\"MAD\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:33+05:30\",\"message\":\"Connection established\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:34+05:30\",\"message\":\"Each HA connection's tunnel IDs: map[0:cykzbns7zu0lra3z2x11fy90deyv2znsdzx34f924k0ktc3geib0]\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:34+05:30\",\"message\":\"+---------------------------------------------------------------+\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:34+05:30\",\"message\":\"|  Your free tunnel has started! Visit it:                      |\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:34+05:30\",\"message\":\"|    https://recommend-dana-events-estimates.trycloudflare.com  |\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:34+05:30\",\"message\":\"+---------------------------------------------------------------+\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:34+05:30\",\"message\":\"Route propagating, it may take up to 1 minute for your new route to become functional\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"connIndex\":1,\"location\":\"CDG\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:34+05:30\",\"message\":\"Connection established\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"connIndex\":2,\"location\":\"MAD\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:35+05:30\",\"message\":\"Connection established\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:36+05:30\",\"message\":\"Each HA connection's tunnel IDs: map[0:cykzbns7zu0lra3z2x11fy90deyv2znsdzx34f924k0ktc3geib0 1:cykzbns7zu0lra3z2x11fy90deyv2znsdzx34f924k0ktc3geib0]\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:36+05:30\",\"message\":\"+---------------------------------------------------------------+\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:36+05:30\",\"message\":\"|  Your free tunnel has started! Visit it:                      |\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:36+05:30\",\"message\":\"|    https://recommend-dana-events-estimates.trycloudflare.com  |\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:36+05:30\",\"message\":\"+---------------------------------------------------------------+\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:36+05:30\",\"message\":\"Route propagating, it may take up to 1 minute for your new route to become functional\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"connIndex\":3,\"location\":\"CDG\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:36+05:30\",\"message\":\"Connection established\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:37+05:30\",\"message\":\"Each HA connection's tunnel IDs: map[0:cykzbns7zu0lra3z2x11fy90deyv2znsdzx34f924k0ktc3geib0 1:cykzbns7zu0lra3z2x11fy90deyv2znsdzx34f924k0ktc3geib0 2:cykzbns7zu0lra3z2x11fy90deyv2znsdzx34f924k0ktc3geib0]\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:37+05:30\",\"message\":\"+---------------------------------------------------------------+\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:37+05:30\",\"message\":\"|  Your free tunnel has started! Visit it:                      |\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:37+05:30\",\"message\":\"|    https://recommend-dana-events-estimates.trycloudflare.com  |\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:37+05:30\",\"message\":\"+---------------------------------------------------------------+\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:37+05:30\",\"message\":\"Route propagating, it may take up to 1 minute for your new route to become functional\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:38+05:30\",\"message\":\"Each HA connection's tunnel IDs: map[0:cykzbns7zu0lra3z2x11fy90deyv2znsdzx34f924k0ktc3geib0 1:cykzbns7zu0lra3z2x11fy90deyv2znsdzx34f924k0ktc3geib0 2:cykzbns7zu0lra3z2x11fy90deyv2znsdzx34f924k0ktc3geib0 3:cykzbns7zu0lra3z2x11fy90deyv2znsdzx34f924k0ktc3geib0]\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:38+05:30\",\"message\":\"+---------------------------------------------------------------+\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:38+05:30\",\"message\":\"|  Your free tunnel has started! Visit it:                      |\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:38+05:30\",\"message\":\"|    https://recommend-dana-events-estimates.trycloudflare.com  |\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:38+05:30\",\"message\":\"+---------------------------------------------------------------+\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:38+05:30\",\"message\":\"Route propagating, it may take up to 1 minute for your new route to become functional\"}"}
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2021-01-14T17:22:38+05:30\",\"message\":\"mux - metrics: Stopping mux metrics updater\"}"}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please show some code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I myself built and improved the above code as it was not working in my case (error in importing json into regex and also i wanted url only to end with a specific subdomain)

```
import json
from re import findall

with open('log.txt', 'r') as logfile:
    for line in logfile.readlines():
        message = json.loads(line)
        lines = message.get('message')
        url = findall(r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))", lines)
        if url:
            url = url[0][0]
            substring = "trycloudflare.com"
            if url.find(substring) != -1:
                print ("Found!")
                print(url)
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by iterating over every single line in the file and loading each line as a JSON into a Python dictionary.

I've provided an implemntation, assuming the following:

- your file is named logs.jsonl in the current working directory
- there will be at most 1 link per message
- there is no newline at the end of the file (might cause error at the empty line)

```py
import json
from re import findall

with open('logs.jsonl', 'r') as logfile:
    for line in logfile.readlines():
        message = json.loads(line)
        message = message['message']
        message = json.loads(message)
        message = message['message']
        url = findall(r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))", message)
        if url:
            url = url[0][0]
            print(url)
```

Note that we also captured Cloudflare's https://1.1.1.1/dns-query url. If you don't want this to happen, feel free to modify the regex to suit your needs. If you hate regex and don't want to look at them for any longer than absolutely necessary, you can use urlparse to make sure the url's domain .endswith(".trycloudflare.com").

Did I write the regex to grab links from a string by myself? No, of course not! Someone already made one before, because finding a link is a common need. Rewriting it would be a waste of time. I just used the one [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-check-url-string/).

Comment: I hope you were able to learn something! (I'm actually just a nineth-grader) If this helped you, you can accept my answer as accepted to give me some credit 

Comment: I will try it today and let you know  (i m also in 12th grade lol)